# Having trouble getting method on mocked object to return fake data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a test for the "MethodToTest" like shown below

```
Public Class UserService()
{
        private IRepository<User> _userRepo;

        public UserService(IRepository<User> userRepo = null)
        {
            _userRepo = userRepo ?? new UserRepository();
        }

        public List<string> MethodToTest(string userName)
        {
            var user = _userRepo.Find(u => u.Email == userName).First<User>();

            //Other stuff that eventually returns a List<string>
        }
}
```

I have the following in my test

```
    [Test]
    public void GetItemsByUserName_UserName_ListOfItems()
    {
        var userName = "AnyString";
        var fakeUserRepo = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();
        var fakeUserList = new List<User>()
        {
        new User()
        {
            Email = userName,
            Roles = new List<Role>()
            {
                new Role()
                {
                    Name="Role1"
                },
                new Role()
                {
                    Name="Role2"
                }
            }
        }
    };
        var fakeUserListQueryable = fakeUserList.AsQueryable<User>();
        var query = new Func<User, bool>(u => u.Email == userName);
        fakeUserRepo.Setup(u => u.Find(query)).Returns(fakeUserListQueryable);
        var userService = new UserService(fakeUserRepo.Object);
        var menu = userService.GetMenuByUserName(userName);

        //Assert Something
    }
```

The problem is that I can't get the find method of the _userRepo to return my fake list of users.

When running the test I get a "Sequence Contains No Elements" when executing

```
_userRepo.Find(u => u.Email == userName).First<User>();
```

in the MethodToTest.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you have an equality issue on the `Func<User, bool>`.  As you know, Moq will setup the fakeUserRepo if the `query` equals the actual Func inside the code you are calling.  However, you are creating a `new Func<User, bool>` in your setup code.  So, when Moq checks equality, it is checking between two different reference types and therefore not setting up the expectation.

I would try something like this:

```
fakeUserRepo.Setup(u => u.Find(It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>())).Returns(fakeUserListQueryable);
```

See if that works and then add the username back in.